# Why do we make a separate function for detecting input for other classes

Tags: lua, love2d

This is from CS50's lectures on Game Development.
We already have a table to detect input (i.e `love.keyboard.keysPressed`) in `main.lua`:

```
function love.keypressed(key)
    -- add to our table of keys pressed this frame
    love.keyboard.keysPressed[key] = true

    if key == 'escape' then
        love.event.quit()
    end
end
```

But we still made another function in `main.lua` to use in other classes:

```
function love.keyboard.wasPressed(key)
    return love.keyboard.keysPressed[key]
end
```

Usage example (Class name: `bird.lua` ):

```
-- just sample code, ignore the functionality
if love.keyboard.wasPressed('space') or love.mouse.wasPressed(1) then
    self.dy = -5
    sounds['jump']:play()
end
```

Code for the whole game can be found [here](https://cdn.cs50.net/games/2019/x/assignments/1/assignment1.zip)

I appreciate you guys taking the time to read through this question

Edit: From what i understood, the

Comment: `love.keypressed` is an event handler, this function is invoked automatically every time a user presses a key.  `love.keyboard.wasPressed` is invoked manually to answer the question "is the key down or up now?"

Comment: Why don't we use `love.keyboard.keysPressed` instead of `love.keyboard.wasPressed`

Comment: it is likely to reduce coupling. "Low coupling refers to a relationship in which one module interacts with another module through a simple and stable interface and does not need to be concerned with the other module's internal implementation" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)

Comment: In your `bird.lua` example, the wrapper function allows both of the conditional expressions to be function calls. It's a little thing, but they may just want to be consistent, instead of checking a table for one and calling a function for the other. Also, since this is for a class, maybe a future assignment will introduce more functionality with in `love.keyboard.wasPressed(key)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `love.keypressed(key)` does not return anything and the table `love.keyboard.keysPressed[key]` is reset after `main.lua` updates so we call a function to directly perform a check at *that specific time* for any input (i.e `love.keyboard.wasPressed`)

Answer (score 1):

Ha I just came across this searching the same question. I think it is so the bird class handles its own key detection/movement.

Since `love.keyboard.keypressed` is a global function, it would always execute, and you'd have to put checks for what state you're in/handle the movement of the bird in main.lua - this way (passing waspressed as a function), the bird class keeps the code associated with it, and main keeps higher level non-specific code